# XCTest - Xcode crashing when trying to record elements inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, xctest

Create a new Swift Xcode Single view project with UI test target.

In Main.storyboard select ViewController, then Editor/Embed in/Navigation Controller.

Change `ViewController.swift` to the following code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate
{
    var _webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView()     {
        _webView = WKWebView()
        _webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = _webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        _webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        _webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

In the generated UI test class (that extends from `XCTestCase`) position cursor in `func testExample()` body, hit the red record button.

Wait until the web view loaded the webpage.

Click inside the webview.

KABOOM! Xcode crashes!

Anyone have any solution for this? It's a game stopper for our UI test pipeline.

Comment: Can you show crash error?

Comment: If Xcode is crashing, file a bug report with Apple. Not much anyone here can do.

Comment: No crash log available. Xcode just quits. Filed bug report --> done! But something so obvious I would think should be well known to Apple or somebody might know something about it. Or I'm living in a parallel universe where nobody actually does UI testing and Apple couldn't give a ****.

Comment: I reported this a year ago.  It was closed by Apple as a duplicate.  It's still happening as of Xcode 9.4.1.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98038